# Docker mysql Collations list

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have an issue. I use wordpress and use duplicator for the duplicate site. In duplicator, I receive error about  `Character set list` and `Collations list`. Looks like that

[image]

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  php:
    build: ./docker_settings/Dockerfile_php
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated

  mysql: 
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wp
      - MYSQL_USER=wp
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
    ports:
      - "8088:3306"
      
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.2.0
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

What i need to do to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

Just change MySQL to MariaDB